# Pressure in Boyle's law

Tags: gas-laws

According to Boyle's law, PV = k as long the temperature and amount of gas remain constant.

In this equation, Is P the pressure inside the container or outside?
I'm confused because I just saw a video on the internet that showed a bag of chips becoming inflated when it was taken to higher altitude. Now in this case the pressure inside the bag didn't change yet the volume changed (let's also assume temperature also remained constant as we moved up)

I know that the bag inflates because the atmospheric pressure decreased as we moved up so the air inside the the bag started exerting a greater force on the walls of the bag but again doesn't this mean pressure increased? It also means that the pressure was directly proportional to volume now??

Comment: See, Boyle law is applied on an equilibrium system. Suppose you increase the external pressure reversible and infinitisimally, the volume will decrease. But to reestablish equilibrium, internal pressure will increase. So you have seen here that $ V \propto \frac{1}{P}$. So it is indeed the internal pressure that is considered.

Comment: In your example, the volume of the bag increased, and the pressure inside the bag decreased.  So what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should gas volume depend on external pressure?

It depends on the internal pressure, which can be:

- equal to the external pressure, as in the case of a container with fully adaptable walls.
- different from the external pressure, as in the case of a container with stressed walls.
- independent of the external pressure, as in the case of pressurized cylinders.

If the chips bag is being taken to higher altitude, internal pressure becomes higher than external pressure, pushing the bag walls against the lower pressure. As the result, the bag expands and increased volume decreases the internal pressure until both pressures are equal again.

At some point, the bag can become fully bloated. Further lifting of the bag causes bag material stress. This leads to the internal pressure becoming bigger than the external pressure, as $p_{\text{ext}} + p_{\text{stress}} = p_{\text{int}}$.

Comment: A stop in a grocery store in Leadville, CO (3000+ meters) reveals highly stressed bags of chips. Care is required handling them.

Answer (score 2):

The gas laws apply to the P, V, n and T of the contained gas. [Engineers also have a different value of R for different gases]. The external pressure can have an effect on the container and then has an effect on the variables. The only real effect is if work is done against an external pressure; then the external pressure determines the work done. A common example is a balloon expanding when it is being inflated. The pressure is one atmosphere until the rubber is stretched. Then the external P has little effect on the pressure unless the strength of the rubber is exceeded. A rigid container will not respond to a change in external pressure.

The atmosphere is a nonrigid container. Air is held in place by the pressure of the surrounding air and by the downward component of gravity. There are two components to the pressure the random motion of molecules and the downward component of gravity. Air heated by conduction from the ground increases its molecular motion and pressure. It will expand and do work against the atmosphere as it expands. This results in an apparent lower density and, since the gravity component of the pressure is less, a faux lower pressure, resulting in wind. If the air is above warm water, there is an added factor. The evaporating water molecules increase the n in PV=nRT increasing the pressure. Less massive water molecules move faster and the expanding air again has a lower gravity component and lower density and winds result. The added complication is that the adiabatically cooled water vapor condenses releasing the heat of vaporization increasing the wind.

The gas laws do apply to these dynamic situations. The math must be some complicated set of differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure of air inside the bag of chips > The atmospheric pressure at high altitude.

This imbalance cause the bag to expand, but (this is Boyle's law) as the bag expands the pressure of air inside the bag falls ... until it becomes equal to the atmospheric pressure.

It seems a bit counterintuitive because a balloon *expands* with "increased pressure", but Boyle's law applies to a *fixed* mass of gas and blowing a ballon is basically adding more air (increasing the mass of gas).